# How to add a curve to rectangle

Tags: modeling

[image]

The shape would look like this if you were looking down at it from the top, I don't know how to represent it as a 3D model. Basically, I want this sort of shape, possibly a bit more curved but besides that, it should look like this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a plane, scale it in *Edit* mode, keep all selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel, press <kbd>V</kbd> in order to bevel the vertices, not the edges, tweak the settings in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Comment: or the finger twisting SHIFT-CTRL-B to go directly to vertex mode

Comment: sure I always forget it  ;)